# Offline SP365 aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-javascript

User is on a mobile device and needs to access a JavaScript application when the device loses internet connection (elevator, basement, etc).

I’m using service workers to cache my files, and plan on handling data with local storage. When the connection is reestablished the app checks local storage and updates accordingly.

Question is when I turn off the internet the .aspx page doesn’t load the cached version. Is this achievable with service workers and a local storage, or is there a more sharepoint way of doing this?

I don’t have access to powershell.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your application, please? Is it an SPFX, SharePoint Hosted App, SharePoint Provider hosted App or a custom page?

Comment: Custom classic page with content-editor webpart.